# @ConfigurationProperties in spring-boot:3.2.X does not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-properties, configurationproperties

I'm testing SpringBoot 3.2.0 in a new project (created from spring's scaffold) and when I configure a `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.path.to.be.parsed")` class (and `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("package.to.be.scanned")` to be scanned) is does not load in Spring Context, but when I try with SpringBoot>3.1.7 all works fine!

I've try with

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.X'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
```

that is working fine, but in the other hand

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.X'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
```

it does not load any of `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "...")` even with `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("package.to.be.scanned")`

**EDIT 2024-01-09:**

This behavior occurs only when `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "...")` class is inside a library, but in the other hand, when `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "...")` is in the whole application, there is not this error!

I've try with `-parameter` flag like in [this migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#parameter-name-retention) adding this configuration to my build.gradle's file

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}
```

I've create [this repo](https://github.com/nicolaspastorbueno-yape/problem-with-configuration-properties) with the problem replication if someone want to help me

- lib-test is published in my maven-local
- ms-test is the "microservice" artifact that use `ListsToFil` class that contains `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.lists-to-fill")`